# Debugging EXE with TLS

Tags: windows, dynamic-analysis, executable

How do I debug an executable that uses TLS callbacks?  It's my understanding that these run before my debugger will attach.

Comment: The Internet Storm Center has a pretty good [write up](https://isc.sans.edu/diary/How+Malware+Defends+Itself+Using+TLS+Callback+Functions/6655) of how you can do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

either:

- patch a debug break (CC int3) or an infinite loop (EB FE jmp $) at the start of the TLS
- try to set a breakpoint as early as possible (like OllyDbg's Options/Events/Make first pause at/System Breakpoint), then set a breakpoint at the TLS' starts
- use a specific plugin, such as OllyAdvanced for OllyDbg.

Note that the conditions for TLS execution are [tricky](http://code.google.com/p/corkami/wiki/PE?show=content#TLS), and debugging might cause an otherwise ignored TLS to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IDA Pro, Ctrl-E (Windows shortcut https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/freefiles/IDA_Pro_Shortcuts.pdf) it will show you entry point. You can directly jump to Main/start function.

Comment: Igor is probably better equipped to comment on this, but TLS was one of the weaknesses in IDA at some point.